# Compared values don't match in an array - VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a following code which is a part of longer code:

```
ReDim arr20(0 To 1) As Variant
arr20(0) = Right(ws2.Range("M21"), 2)
arr20(1) = Right(ws2.Range("P21"), 2)


For i = 0 To UBound(arr1)
If Mid(arr(i), 4, 2) = arr20(0) - 9 + i Then
msgbox "Incorrect file in a folder" & " " & "-" & " " & Left(arr(i), 5)
End If
Next i
```

which results in Mid(arr(i), 4, 2) = 13 and arr20(0) - 9 + i = 13 but VBA does not agree and goes directly to false condition of if/end if even though 13 equals 13.

I have a hunch that formatting is off for first or latter value but I don't know how to fix it.

If I debug.print both values I see there's a hidden blank space in front of second value, can this be a root cause? If so, how to resolve it?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: mid returns a string and `"1"<>1`

Comment: `If Mid(arr(i), 4, 2) = cstr(arr20(0) - 9 + i) Then`

Comment: @ScottCraner Fast as lightning, Scott. Thanks, it's working. So my hunch was correct and it was string. Could you please elaborate on "cstr"?

Comment: CStr = Change to String.  We are changing the number returned by the math to a string so we can then equate two strings.

Comment: @ScottCraner Noted, perfect.